# Importing the Nock npm module creates error when running npm test

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nock

If I remove the nock import I won't get an error message. I've already npm installed `nock`.

#### Test file

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import { promiseHandler } from '../middleware'
import * as actions from './index'
import nock from 'nock'
import expect from 'expect'

const middlewares = [promiseHandler]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)
```

#### Error Message

```
 FAIL  src/actions/index.test.js
Runtime Error
  - TypeError: debug is not a function
        at overrideClientRequest (node_modules/nock/lib/intercept.js:221:3)
        at activate (node_modules/nock/lib/intercept.js:320:3)
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/nock/lib/intercept.js:383:1)
        at Runtime._execModule (node_modules/jest-cli/src/Runtime/Runtime.js:261:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/nock/lib/recorder.js:6:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/nock/index.js:1:135)
        at Object.<anonymous> (src/actions/index.test.js:4:39)
        at jasmine2 (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/src/index.js:252:16)
        at handle (node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:41:8)
        at process.<anonymous> (node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:47:3)
        at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
        at process.emit (events.js:185:7)
        at handleMessage (internal/child_process.js:718:10)
        at Pipe.channel.onread (internal/child_process.js:444:11)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't aware that my project was using the Jest testing framework, 
subsequently the module needed to be "unmocked" by doing `jest.unmock('nock');` before the import.